# How to use .NET Framework 4.0 project into .NET Framework 3.5 project?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, class-library

I want to use my class library project, which is created in Framework 4.0. Now i want to use that Class library into my .Net Framework 3.5 Class library project Via References.
When i try to build my .NET Framework 3.5 project i am getting following error 
"The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary4' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

But i have referred my .net framework 4.0 project in .net framework 3.5.

Is it possible to achieve this? If so Can i know the steps to proceed further???

pls guide me..

Comment: It is probably pointless to note that the word "class" is spelled with two ess-es.  Accuracy is *very* important when you ask a question like this.

Comment: @hans passant: i have edited my question..